# What elements are retained between invocations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

It's [best practice](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking) to reuse client connections in `main.py` to avoid unneeded network activity

What other elements are stored between invocations?  What determines this?

For example, variables are not retained:

```
somevar = None

def main(event, context):
    try:
        print(somevar) # this fails every run
    except:
        pass
    somevar = 1 # this is set but not retained between runs
```

Arguments in argparse *are* retained:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--somevar', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

def main(event, context):
    print(args.somevar) # This prints False after a coldstart and True every other time
    args.somevar = True
    print(args.somevar) # This always prints True as expected
```

Comment: `main` is using a local variable, `somevar`.

Answer (score 3):

The following documentation: [Cloud Functions Execution Environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#functions-concepts-stateless-python) provides a detailed description of the environment present for a Cloud Function and what state is available / maintained (if any) between invocations.

In your example, you said that variable updates are not retained but in reality, they are if we use the Python `global` construct.

The above documentation outlines that, at the highest level, the state of a function includes:

- Function variables
- File System
- Network

See also:

- [Global keyword in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/)